# Simple issues with setInterval

Tags: javascript

so sorry for a basic qn like this. This is my simple JS code to do a timer. I was hoping to print the countdown number periodically. I tested the rest of the code and it seems to work, however it gives me sth weird when I add the setInterval command. I am not sure why. I hence seek an explanation and how to correct it.
Also, when it works, the new reloaded number should replace the old number right. For instance when 4 appears, it simply replaces 5 during the countdown.

Code:

```
var x = prompt("Time till take off");



function printTimer (){
  document.write(x)
}

while (x > 0) {

  setInterval(printTimer,1000)
  x = x -1;
}

if (x=1){
  document.write("Rocket taken off")}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your code, `x` is not the time till take off, it's how many 1 second timers are started. Also, `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet I think does what you're looking for. Further explanation is in the code comments for a little context:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('count-down');

/**
 * Initiates a countdown from given time in seconds
 * @param {number} count
 */
function countDown(count) {

    // Create the interval and save it in a variable 'interval'.
    // We need it later when the countdown reaches 0
    var interval = setInterval(function writeCount() {

        // If time till takeoff is greater than 0, we print the current
        // count and then decrement the count, so that next time count
        // will be ( count - 1 )
        if (count > 0) {
            output.innerText = count;
            count--;
            // OR: count -= 1';
            // OR: count = count - 1';
            // are all equivalent
        }
        // Otherwise we write a final value, and clear the timeout
        // so that we only get this final value once. If not cleared
        // the next second count will be -1, and this else block would
        // be re-executed.
        else {
            output.innerText = "Rocket taken off";
            clearTimeout(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countDown(prompt("Time till take off"));
```

```html
<div id="count-down"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @jeffrey-westerkamp's solution is elegant and the way to go to achieve your result. However, if you are curious why your current code isn't working, here's what's happening.

There are a 3 big issues.

1. You are using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

`setInterval` will call a function repeatedly, until it is cancelled, at the specified time interval.

This would mean that if the rest of your code was working, it would output "10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10..." "9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9.." etc., until you cancelled each number's interval.

`setTimeout` calls the specified function *once* at the specified amount of time in the future.

2. You need to bind the variable `x` to your call to each `setTimeout`.

Right now, each time `printTimer` is called, it looks at the value of x. But here's the thing: the value of x is going to be 0 *for each call*.

Why? The while loop queues up all the calls to `setTimeout` (or in your case `setInterval`. At the specified time in the future, `printTimer` gets called. When it does, it looks for the variable x. By the time the first `printTimer` call runs, x has long since been set to zero from the while loop.

3. You need to make the delay at which `setTimeout` is called dependent on the position in the countdown sequence.

A for loop makes this a little bit more intuitive. Something like this:

```
function printTimer(count) {
  if (count===1){ console.log("Rocket taken off"); }
  else { console.log(count); }
}

for (var i=0;i<x;i++) {
  (function(count){
    setTimeout(printTimer.bind(null,x-count),1000*count);
  })(i);
}
```

That strange syntax inside the for loop is called an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), or an immediately invoked function expression. Another way to write that for loop without the IIFE would be using let instead of var:

```
for (let i=0;i<x;i++) { //also works
  setTimeout(printTimer.bind(null,x-i),1000*i);
}
```

If this is confusing, check out this section of [You Don't Know JS: Loops+Closure](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure).

Comment: Very good addition! I entirely dodged the concerns you describe here in my implementation.